# Building a cache with Talend SOAP webservices

Tags: caching, esb, talend

I am trying to build a cache for a SOAP webservice in Talend : an input parameter "reinitCache" can be set to true if the cache has to be rebuilt (like once a day). Otherwise the cache is simply read , and the SOAP response is sent.

Unfortunately, I tried to do this with tHash components, and while it is working well inside the studio, once deployed on Karaf it is not working anymore : around 50% of the time, an error "tHash is not initialized" is risen.[image: Sample of my job]. It seems like tHash components are not always accessible.

Is there a safer way to do it ? I also tried with tBuffer without success.

Comment: Talend jobs usually won't reside in memory after they were run. Even if, the garbage collector would do its job anyways. Astonishing that sometimes you still have data. I suspect you need to store temporary data in a database, maybe using memory tables at best.

Comment: I think that as the tESBProviderRequest component is in a "Keep Listening" mode, it prevents the job from terminating and thus the GC to intervene. Storing in table/file is perhaps the only option in my case.