# Reading from and Writing to a centralized cache using Talend

Tags: caching, talend

I want to implement caching in Talend. By this I mean that I want to read from and write to cache memory through Talend. The cache memory will be a centralized one. I read about tHashInput/Output which are used to read from and write to cache memory.

My questions are:

1. Are there any other components apart from tHashInput/Output to read/write to cache?
2. In tHashOutput we have a drop down menu named Data Write Model. What is its significance? I ask this because I have a scenario where I would be using a centralized cache memory where many people would be reading from and writing to cache. In that case what other options drop down menu can have?

Answer (score 0):

1. tHashOutput/Input are the best components for cache . You can also use tBufferOutput/Input but you won't be able to put more than 1 tBufferOutput for each job.
2. I don't think there are other options in this dropdown menu.

For each job, the cache used by tHash components is only usable within this execution of a job. You won't be able to recover it during another run.
If you are using webservices (as providing a SOAP method for a webservice with talend for example), tHashOutput is not very reliable : from time to time the cache will be accessible, but not always.

You Could check one of my previous questions about this : 
[Building a cache with Talend SOAP webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971993/building-a-cache-with-talend-soap-webservices)